# ValueError: could not convert string to float while converting fractions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df.head()

        country      league home_odds draw_odds away_odds             datetime      home_team           away_team home_score away_score
381084  Iceland  League Cup    167/50   329/100    63/100  2016-02-16 19:15:00      Kopavogur  Vikingur Reykjavik          0          1
381085  Iceland  League Cup   463/100    173/50    47/100  2016-02-14 21:15:00           Fram            Stjarnan          0          3
381086  Iceland  League Cup      9/25     99/25    303/50  2016-02-14 19:15:00   KR Reykjavik              Haukar          1          1
381087  Iceland  League Cup      9/25   393/100   611/100  2016-02-14 19:00:00  Thor Akureyri          Leiknir F.          5          0
381088  Iceland  League Cup     11/25   353/100   251/50  2016-02-14 17:00:00         Akranes           Grindavik          5          0
```

I am applying the following function:

```
def convert(s):
    if '/' in str(s):  # is a fraction
        num, den = s.split('/')
        return 1 + (int(num) / int(den))
    else:
        return s.astype(float)

odds_cols = ['home_odds', 'draw_odds', 'away_odds']
df[odds_cols] = df[odds_cols].apply(convert)
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.2\scratches\scratch_2.py", line 70, in <module>
    df[odds_cols] = df[odds_cols].apply(convert)....
    return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '167/50'
```

How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` provides a row or column to the function whereas you want the row sent element by element. Use `applymap` as in the following code (I assume 1.0 + is needed for how you want odds shown). In case the DF includes elements which cannot be converted, basic error checking replaces these with NaN and such rows can then printed for you to check.

```
def convert(s):
    if isinstance(s, str):
        if '/' in str(s):  # is a fraction
            num, den = s.split('/')
            try:
                val = 1.0 + int(num) / int(den)
            except ValueError:
                val = None
        else:
            try:
                val = float(s)
            except ValueError:
                val = None
    else:
        val = None
    return val

df[odds_cols] = df[odds_cols].applymap(convert)

print(df[df.isna().any(axis = 1)]) # omit unless checking wanted
```

Comment: I am gettinng a new error: `in convert
    return s.astype(float)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'`

Comment: Code edited to include error checking. Hope this is now useful.